# R- How to use diff() and grouping simultaneously?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with values

```
cust_no name    trans_date     amount
1122    abc     2014-03-10     2000
1122    abc     2014-03-15     300
4444    pqr     2014-01-10     1000
4444    pqr     2014-01-15     1000
4444    pqr     2014-02-15     1000
7777    xyz     2014-01-10     34
7777    xyz     2014-01-11     444
7777    xyz     2014-01-17     2344
7777    xyz     2014-01-30     345
```

I wish to calculate days difference between two transactions for the **same** customer. My output should be like

```
cust_no name  trans_date       amount TimeDiff    
1122     abc 2014-03-10         2000  0
1122     abc 2014-03-15         300   5
4444     pqr 2014-01-10         1000  0
4444     pqr 2014-01-15         1000  5
4444     pqr 2014-02-15         1000  30
7777     xyz 2014-01-10         34    0
7777     xyz 2014-01-11         444   1
7777     xyz 2014-01-17         2344  6
7777     xyz 2014-01-30         345   13
```

I tried the following code (without using the `diff()` of course)

```
> for( i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){
+   if(ds$cust_no[i]==ds$cust_no[i+1]){
+     ds$TimeGap[i]<-ds$trans_Date[i+1]-ds$trans_Date[i]
+   }
+ }
```

But I don't get the desired output as shown above. Instead, I get the below one, which essentially calculates time gap between every value of transaction_date of the table, which is evident from the negative values.

```
1122 abc 2014-03-10 2000  0
1122 abc 2014-03-15 300   5
4444 pqr 2014-01-10 1000  -64
4444 pqr 2014-01-15 1000  5
4444 pqr 2014-02-15 1000  30
7777 xyz 2014-01-10 34    -35
7777 xyz 2014-01-11 444   1
7777 xyz 2014-01-17 2344  6
7777 xyz 2014-01-30 345   13
```

Comment: which column refers to the customer?

Comment: Apologies. I have edited the question with column names

Comment: `transaction_date` doesn't match in the desired input and output

Comment: @DavidArenburg Your solution worked actually!! Why did you delete it? Please re-post.

Comment: Because @shadow posted the same solution adding a `dplyr` one too, so no need in two exactly the same solutions

Comment: RESPECT! @DavidArenburg  Indeed the solution posted by shadow worked like a charm! The planet has become an awesome place to live in!!

Comment: @sunitprasad1 A base R option would be `df$TimeDIff <- with(df, ave(as.numeric(Date), CustomerNo, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `ave` or the packages `dplyr` or `data.table` to calculate by groups.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(cust_no = c(1122L, 1122L, 4444L, 4444L, 4444L, 
7777L, 7777L, 7777L, 7777L), name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("abc", "pqr", "xyz"), class = "factor"), 
    trans_date = structure(c(16139, 16144, 16080, 16085, 16116, 
    16080, 16081, 16087, 16100), class = "Date"), amount = c(2000L, 
    300L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 34L, 444L, 2344L, 345L)), .Names = c("cust_no", 
"name", "trans_date", "amount"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

**base solution** (from @akrun)

```
df$time_diff <- with(df, ave(as.numeric(trans_date), cust_no, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x))))
```

**dplyr solution**

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(cust_no) %>% mutate(time_diff = c(0, diff(trans_date)))
```

**data.table solution**

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, time_diff :=c(0, diff(trans_date)), by=cust_no][]
```

Comment: Apologies for not putting up the column names. I have edited the question with column names

Comment: @shadow You could also include the base R option with `ave`

Comment: @shadow I used `df$TimeDIff <- with(df, ave(as.numeric(Date), CustomerNo, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x))))`

Comment: @akrun I was actually getting an error because I had used `ave` in a wrong way.  `df$TimeDIff <- with(df, ave(df$trans_date, cust_no, diff(df$trans_date)` (didn't convert `Date` to `numeric`)

Comment: @sunitprasad1 I guess it got solved by the modification

Comment: @akrun I'm not able to get the logic behind using `FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x)` instead of `FUN=diff(ds$trans_date)` . What is the difference between the two?

Comment: @sunitprasad1 The length of the output returned by the `diff` function is one less than the length of the input vector/column. check `diff(c(1,3,7))`.  Regarding the dfifference between your code and mine, your code is taking the `diff` on the whole column instead of taking the group (`cust_no`) into account.  It is like doing `diff(df$trans_date)` alone.  Having said that you will get warnings/error because the length will be less. In order to get the lengths correct, we can pad it with `0` or `NA` `c(0, diff(x))`

Comment: Yes, I indeed got an error. Thanks for clarifying @akrun